# Update column values in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

i am trying to make an update operation in AWS Athena for my column value that has doubles quotes.

I tried:

```sql
UPDATE "table_name" 
SET user_id = REPLACE(user_id, '"', '')
```

Is update not supported in Athena?

Answer (score 3):

`UPDATE` is not available in the Athena instruction set.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ddl-sql-reference.html

It is not the purpose of Athena to edit source data.

You could however perform the string replace after the select using `replace` https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html.

```
replace(string, search, replace) → varchar#
Replaces all instances of search with replace in string.

If search is an empty string, inserts replace in front of every character and at the end of the string.
```

Eg

```
SELECT user_id, replace(user_id, '"', '') FROM "table_name";
```